# DataGrid Binding - don't show null entries from list

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, data-binding, datagrid

I have following XAML

```
<DataGrid Name="grid">
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Technology" Binding="{Binding Name}" />
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Version" Binding="{Binding Number}" />
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

And following classes

```
public class Data
{
    public List<Technology> Technologies { get; set; }
}

public class Technology
{
    public string Name { get; set;}
    public int Number { get; set; }
}
```

List `Technologies` is the source of data for datagrid. There are all list items in datagrid by this solution.

I want show only items where `Number` is not null. What is the best way to achieve it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When u set the collection to the ItemsSource, do it via a `ListCollectionView`...

```
      grid.ItemsSource
            = new ListCollectionView(Technologies);
      ((ListCollectionView)grid.ItemsSource).Filter += IsNotNull;
```

Have a predicate like this....

```
      private bool IsNotNull(object obj )
      {
         return ((Technology)obj).Number != null;
      }
```

Although a curious question, your `Number` property is `int` not `int?` how can it be Null?

Also I suggest you to use `ObservableCollection<Technology>` for your benefit of auto filtering when `Number` changes. Also make sure `Technology` has `INotifyPropertyChanged` implemented.

Comment: Good point about `Number` not being nullable, I guess that's a typo

Comment: That's a typo :) I ment 0, not null. Thank your for advice about ´ObservableCollection´, I think I don't need this in my application. Nothing changes ´Number´.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a `DataTrigger` on `DataGridRow`

```
<DataGrid Name="grid">
    <DataGrid.RowStyle>
        <Style TargetType="DataGridRow">
            <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Number}" Value="{x:Null}">
                    <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed"/>
                </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </DataGrid.RowStyle>
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Technology" Binding="{Binding Name}" />
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Version" Binding="{Binding Number}" />
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

Alternatively you could bind `Visibility` for `DataGridRow` to `Number` and use a Converter which returns `Visibility.Collapsed` for `null` and `Visibility.Visible` otherwise

Comment: @Melak, this may cause issues with alternating row styles coz suppose if alternate rows have say peach background color then if row 1 is ok, row 2 is null, row 3 is ok then you will see row1 and row3 joined with peach background.

Comment: @AngelWPF: Yes, that will be a problem if alternating row colors is used. The problem with using a filter on a `CollectionView` is that it doesn't update automatically when `Number` changes. So it all comes down to how this is meant to be used

Comment: Well if List<Technology> was ObservableCollection<Technology> then it will filter on property changes as well.

Comment: @AngelWPF: Using an `ObservableCollection` as `SourceCollection` for `ListCollectionView` won't make the `Filter` trigger once a property changes. Or did I missunderstand your comment?

Comment: Hang on there seems to be some mistake... if the item is `INotifyPropertyChanged` and the collection is `Observable` then the property changes "inherently" cascade up to the CollectionView to perform Sorting, Grouping and FIltering automatically without `CollectionView.Refresh()`... I have seen this happening.